# does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bitcode, xcode14

I am facing this error while installing in device but build is running perfectly in simulator.
As suggest in error i have disabled bitcode in this library but still getting this error while trying to run in device.
Xcode version:- 14.1

Showing All Errors Only
'/Users/unnati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrainPuzzle-chbwvweeswlzwpaaoinoodosfdww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/AppLovinMediationByteDanceAdapter/libByteDanceAdapter.a(ALByteDanceMediationAdapter.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/unnati/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BrainPuzzle-chbwvweeswlzwpaaoinoodosfdww/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/AppLovinMediationByteDanceAdapter/libByteDanceAdapter.a' for architecture arm64

As suggest in error i have disabled bitcode in this library but still getting this error while trying to run in device also updated the library still facing this issue.

Comment: yes, Problem has been solved.

Comment: can you tell me how?

Comment: @heximal I am facing this after upgrading my flutter. Have checked that all BITCODE_ENABLED are "NO". Can you please tell how you solved it?

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're using a library/dependency that may still have bitcode enabled. (AppLovin?)

Make sure all the dependencies u use have bitcode disabled, and update them to their latest version.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode file system click Pods -> AppLovinMediationByteDanceAdapter -> Build Settings -> Build Options -> change Enable Bitcode from "yes" to "no".

Answer (score 1):

Rdev and LA's answers worked for me, with a twist. I had a working Share Extension, and this error started popping after I upgraded flutter without any change. For me, `Enable Bitcode` option was not visible because `Basic` tab was selected instead of `All` (in Build Settings Window); changed them to know for all the 3 (Project-Runner, Target-Runner and Target-Share Extension). Additionally, I changed `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` to NO also for all the 3.

*Edit*: nitpicks